ROS2 opencv not found
I am trying to compile ROS2 Jazzy with CMake and i get the error

fatal error: cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h: No such file or directory
1 | #include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

but i have already installed cv_bridge and it is detected when i run the code
ros2 pkg list | grep cv_bridge.

Also i am getting some error from Cython

Error compiling Cython file

How do i fix these?
